# Superclasses methods for subclasses Java

Tags: java, methods, subclass, superclass

Does a subclass need to rewrite each method of the superclass or it isn't mandatory to do so but the subclass can override some methodes of the superclass. I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a subclass wishes to introduce unique behavior for invocation of a method that it inherited, then that method *must* be overridden.

The most common cases for this:  `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode` are all eligible to be overridden for all of your custom classes, given that your custom class doesn't want to leverage `Object#toString`, `Object#equals` or `Object#hashCode`, which are all "unhelpful" for your custom implementations.

If a subclass *does not* wish to introduce unique behavior for invocation of a method that it inherited, then this is unnecessary.  You can rely on the parent class' behavior instead.

If your parent class is `abstract`, then **you have no choice** but to implement what methods the parent class chose not to implement.

If you're implementing an interface, the same principle as abstract classes applies - because the interface does not implement anything itself, you **must** implement the methods that the interface prescribes.

Comment: I'd suggest to put the _"if a subclass does not .."_ paragraph first

Comment: Not entirely sold that the word flow is inappropriate there @MarkRotteveel; I merely wrote what came to mind first.  I feel like explaining why you'd want to *first* is more ideal than explaining why you *don't*.

Comment: I think that that "does not wish"-paragraph answers the actual question, and then the rest serves as further explanation and details. Right now, the first two paragraphs don't read as an answer to this question, or the wrong answer to this question (the use of _must_ in the first paragraph is confusing in that context). And only when the third paragraph is read it falls into place.

Answer (score 2):

Subclasses are not required to override any parent methods, even though they can. The only way to force a child class to override a method is to make that method abstract (and the parent class has to be abstract as well).